# Why is java allowing this to compile and what is it interpreting multiple + signs as in this case?

Tags: java

Wasn't sure exactly how to word the question, but I noticed something strange while constructing a date. I found that if I construct a date like this

```
new Date(+ 1)
```

it compiled just fine, and so did

```
new Date(+ + + 1)
```

If I execute the following, the output is 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1;
    System.out.println(+ + + + x);
}
```

Can anyone explain what it is that the JVM thinks I am doing?

Comment: System.out.println(x + + + + + + x); Prints out 2... And System.out.println(x + + + x + + + x); Prints 3...

Comment: `System.out.println(- - - - x);` works, so why shouldn't this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the [unary operator (+)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).  You can always add a + to a numeral and that will give you the positive value of the number.

Because you're spacing the tokens out in such a fashion, the lexer is *not* interpreting anything here as incrementation, so you're adding four unary (+) operations to a value 1.

Answer (score 4):

It's treating it like this:

```
System.out.println(+ (+ (+ (+ x))));
```

This is no different than

```
System.out.println(- (- (- (- x))));
```